# Unity and map services

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, maps

I want to use the world map in Unity and have been looking at the API of various map services. I need to show a screenshot (a static map with markers) on the screen, and move to the full map view to navigate it after clicking on it.

MapBox managed to display the map with the selected coordinates and add test markers, but that's all I can do with a query like this: https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/static/url-https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mapbox.com%2Fimg%2Frocket.png(-76.9,38.9)/-76.9,38.9,15/1000x1000?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGVuZGVhZCIsImEiOiJja2F1dha4egixnnfhmnvtc2u0y3bua2ntin0.GGOyhgN_fEqtPpPc5n6OLg because this request returns a jpg image.

They also have a plugin for Unity, but it's only used in 3d projects and does not allow me to configure the display in 2d.

In MapBox, the mapping I need is implemented using JavaScript for Web and Java for Android. On Android I can do what I need. I can connect to the API on Android, but will I be able to use it in Unity later?

It's the same with Google maps.

Actually, the question is, did someone work with map services in Unity? And how can this be implemented correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but I used Mapbox in Unity (the Mapbox plugin) to create a AR Soundscape by "registering" GameObjects to coordinates and moving them in real-time when the map is moved.

Your problem sounds an awful lot like the one I solved with that.

Basically you provide the Lat/Lon values for your objects and convert them to Unity world space coordinates using the `AbstractMap.GeoToWorldPosition()` function.
I used a raycast to actually pull that off in-engine, which is quite convenient.

//Edit:
Unity is quite capable of handling 2D projects. You just have to configure it properly and build your project around it.

The following is the class that I use to handle all positioning-related calculations. Maybe it's of some help to you.

```cs
namespace TehMightyPotato.Positioning
{
    [Serializable]
    public class GeoPosition
    {
        [Tooltip(
            "Update frequency of position polling. Update every n-th frame. 1 is every frame, 60 is every 60th frame.")]
        [Range(1, 60)]
        public int positionUpdateFrequency = 1;

        [Tooltip("Should the object have a specified altitude?")]
        public bool useYOffset = false;

        [Tooltip("If useMeterConversion is activated the yOffsets unit is meters, otherwise its unity units.")]
        public bool useMeterConversion = false;

        [Tooltip("The actual y position of the object in m or unity units depending on useMeterConversion.")]
        public float yOffset = 0;
        
        [Tooltip("X is LAT, Y is LON")]public Vector2d geoVector;

        [HideInInspector] public float worldRelativeScale;

        
        // Apply the result of this function to your gameobjects transform.position on every frame to keep them on this position. 
        public Vector3 GetUnityWorldSpaceCoordinates(AbstractMap map)
        {
            UpdateWorldRelativeScale(map);
            var worldSpaceCoordinates = map.GeoToWorldPosition(geoVector, false);
            if (useYOffset)
            {
                worldSpaceCoordinates.y = yOffset;
            }

            return worldSpaceCoordinates;
        }

        public void UpdateWorldRelativeScale(AbstractMap map)
        {
            worldRelativeScale = map.WorldRelativeScale;
        }

        public void SetGeoVectorFromRaycast(Vector3 position, AbstractMap map, LayerMask layerMask)
        {
            var ray = new Ray(position, Vector3.down);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hitInfo, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
            {
                geoVector = map.WorldToGeoPosition(hitInfo.point);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("Raycast did not hit the map. Did you turn on map preview?");
            }
        }

        public void SetYOffsetFromRaycast(AbstractMap map, Vector3 position, LayerMask layerMask)
        {
            UpdateWorldRelativeScale(map);
            // using raycast because of possible y-non-zero maps/ terrain etc.
            var ray = new Ray(position, Vector3.down);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hitInfo, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
            {
                var worldSpaceDistance = Vector3.Distance(position, hitInfo.point);
                if (useMeterConversion)
                {
                    yOffset = worldSpaceDistance * worldRelativeScale;
                }
                else
                {
                    yOffset = worldSpaceDistance;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("Could not find map below. Is map preview turned on?");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I switched to Android platform with Google Maps and have ho problems with it.

Comment: That's great! Maybe this answer will be helpful to some other people then :)